# Enteprise level VMware hypervisors, ESX, ESXi, what programming languages are they programmed in?

Tags: kernel, vmware, virtualization

I did not see this question/answer anywhere so here it is: Does anybody know what programming languages (or language) the VMware ESX/ESXi hypervisor is programmed in? I am interested in the hypervisor code as well as code in features such as high availability, DRS, fault tolerance, etc. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 5):

The VMware ESX/ESXi hypervisor, kernel, and device drivers are written in C.  The management layers are generally written in C++, but there is a lot of C.  Plus there are a lot of of bash, perl, and python scripts.

Comment: Just curious, do you have a source for this?